# Unknown Column when using where clause in set relation n-n

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

when I use set relation n-n with where clause like this

```
$crud->set_relation_n_n('actors', 'film_actor', 'actor', 'film_id', 'actor_id', 'fullname', null, $this->db->like('actor.actor_name','Katja' , 'both');
```

this is not working (Unknown column 'actor.actor_name' in 'where clause') but when I put in the where clause column from the first table it would work. like this

```
$crud->set_relation_n_n('actors', 'film_actor', 'actor', 'film_id', 'actor_id', 'fullname', null, $this->db->like('film.film_name','taken' , 'both');
```

So I cannot access the fields from the selected table!!
I need to search the name of the actors, Could someone please help

Is there a shorter way as using the actor's table as the main table, and then filter it with $crud->where()?

thanks

Comment: Hi, Can you share the the table details, if you refer to example mentioned in the grocery crud then it doesn't have actor_name but fullname. 

Also where clause can be added like that, 
$crud->set_relation_n_n('user_id', 'user_device', 'user', 'device_id', 'user_id', 'email_address', 'priority', array('user_id'=>2));

References:https://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/794-set-relation-n-n-where-clause/

Comment: Hi, well I have actor_name the problem is I can’t put where clause on the selected table ( actor) just the main table( film)